# Column `word` is not found. dplyr group_by error

Tags: r, dplyr

```r
result <- data_full %>%
+   dplyr::filter(!is.na(word)) %>% 
+   dplyr::group_by(word) %>% # 
+   dplyr::summarise(freq = n()) %>%  
+   dplyr::ungroup() %>% # 
+   dplyr::arrange(desc(freq)) %>% 
+   dplyr::filter(freq != 1) %>% 
+   dplyr::mutate(word_len = nchar(word)) %>% 
+   dplyr::filter(word_len != 1) %>% 
+   dplyr::select(-word_len)
```

Produces:

> Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
> Column `word` is not found.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> In addition: Warning message:
> In is.na(word) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

i don't know what wrong it is..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, `word` is not a column of `data_full`.

The error message also suggests that `word` is a closure. This would be the case with something like `word = sym("column name")`. In this case you want to put `!!` before `word`. E.g.: `dplyr::filter(!is.na(!!word))`

Also call `colnames(data_full)` to list all the column names of your dataset. Perhaps the column you are after is called `Word` or `words` instead of `word`?